# Offline move trainer software

Tags: learning, software

I am looking for an offline move trainer software like the one chessable has. I am currently looking at PGN's with same opening and I would like to practice these games. For instance, I am looking at Sicilian Najdorf Scheveningen style and have collected Kasparov's game (roughly around 40 of them). I would like to faithfully repeat the moves made by Kasparov in each of these games, while the White's move is made by the computer. I would greatly appreciate suggestions. It need not necessarily be spaced repetition though it would be great.

Comment: What kind of training do you have in mind? Do you specifically want spaced repetition, or just a a software which allows you to follow a specific opening (e.g. versus a computer which plays a random line from the opening)?

Comment: @ATLPoly Added details to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Chess Position Trainer. Also Chessbase has a training mode where you can create quizzes for certain moves.

Answer (score 0):

One piece of software that you might find useful is called Chess Hero. It takes a pgn file you supply and will have you do guess the move training, with it making the move for the other side. It also has an engine running and will tell you if it considers your move better than what was actually played or worse if you chosen something different, and keeps a score of how well you do. Chessbase 15 also has the new replay training feature, which basically does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with LucasChess, option "Play like a gradmaster".

Though you can't provide your own pgns, you can select the player and the opening.